# How to merge in Dovecot extra fields from system accounts to passwd-file format?

Tags: email-server, dovecot, disk-space-utilization, mailbox

I'm running an Ubuntu mail server with Dovecot 2.2.33 and am using system accounts:

```
passdb {
  driver = pam
```

I have about 100 mail users.

I would like to impose per-user storage quotas, but the Dovecot docs on [per-user quota configuration](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/quota/#quota-configuration-per-user) say:

> The Passwd userdb doesn’t support extra fields. That’s why you can’t
> directly set users’ quota limits to passwd file. One possibility would
> be to write a script that reads quota limits from another file, merges
> them with passwd file and produces another passwd-file, which you
> could then use with Dovecot’s Passwd-file.

Does anyone have an example of such a script? I'm not clear from [the docs](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/passwd_file/) how the password itself is handled, for example. Or is there some other workaround that wouldn't entail having to migrate to a virtual user setup to get per-user quotas?

Comment: Ah OK. That sounds like an answer to my question. So can I replace my existing `userdb` stanza with something calling multiple dbs? I'm not clear how that's done, but [like this](https://pastebin.com/rCJUSi5e)?

Comment: never tried it myself, but looks close. however still need to change the real lookup to `continue-ok` on success and the partial quota lookup to `continue` on success. you do not want a match for entries that *only* appear in the quota file, but not (or no longer) in the system password database, so the quota-lookup must not modify found state, that must come from the main passwd lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to merge your user list with your quota configuration is to [chain multiple user databases](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/user_databases_userdb).

You want the original lookup to remember the result and continue, and the additional lookup to only continue. That will still get the *found* status (whether a user exists) from your original passwd file, but it will continue to check additional userdb lookups, the results of which [are merged](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/user_databases_userdb/#authentication-user-database).

```
userdb {
  driver = passwd
  result_success = continue-ok
  # result_failure = continue
  result_internalfail = return-fail
}
userdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = /etc/dovecot/quotas
  result_success = continue
  # result_failure = continue
  result_internalfail = return-fail
}

# where /etc/dovecot/quotas is a passwd-style file
#  only associate usernames and userdb options via the added column (*seven* colons):
user1:::::::userdb_quota_rule=*:bytes=512M
user2:::::::userdb_quota_rule=*:bytes=256M
```

Be sure to add a reasonable default so that users created without customizing their quota through that file are also sensibly restricted.